# google::dense_hash_map vs std::tr1::unordered_map?

Tags: iphone, c++, ios

I'm working on a Mobile Game for several platforms ( Android, iOS, and some maybe even some kind of console in the future ).

I'm trying to decide whether to use [tr1::unordered_map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unordered_map_%28C++%29) or [google::dense_hash_map](http://google-sparsehash.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/dense_hash_map.html) to retrieve Textures from a Resource Manager (for later binding using OpenGL). Usually this can happen quite a few times per second (N per frame, where my Game is running at ~60 fps)

Considerations are:

- Performance (memory and cpu wise)
- Portability

Any ideas or suggestions are welcome.

Comment: im interested why do you must use a hash map at all? i dont know anything about the platform youre using, but it just sounds weird for the purpose you describe.

Comment: This way to go for Texture management is not that uncommon, Ogre3D uses a similar approach ( http://www.ogre3d.org/docs/api/html/classOgre_1_1TextureManager.html )

Comment: It is impossible to give a good answer to this question. Maybe it will make no discernable difference at all. Why don't you measure it and see?

Comment: Why do you think it's impossible? I'm asking for some experience here too... I could measure portability in my current platform ( iOS ), but not on Android just yet. I would love some information about the portability issues too. I don't think the question is impossible to answer ( best guesses are welcome of course )

Comment: Thanks for bringing Google Sparsehash to my attention (Oh, and: profile it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://attractivechaos.wordpress.com/2008/10/07/another-look-at-my-old-benchmark/

http://attractivechaos.wordpress.com/2008/08/28/comparison-of-hash-table-libraries/

Answer (score 1):

go with the STL for standard containers.  They have predictable behavior, and can be used seamlessly in STL algos/iterators.  You're also given some performance guarantees by the STL.

This should also guarantee portability.  Most compilers have the new standard implemented.

Answer (score 0):

In a C++ project I developed, I was wondering something similar: which one was best, `tr1:unordered_map`, `boost::unordered_map` or `std::map`? I ended up declaring a `typedef`, controllable at compilation:

```
#ifdef UnorderedMapBoost
typedef boost::unordered_map<cell_key, Cell> cell_map;
#else
#ifdef UnorderedMapTR1
typedef std::tr1::unordered_map<cell_key, Cell> cell_map;
#else
typedef std::map<cell_key, Cell>  cell_map;
#endif // #ifdef UnorderedMapTR1
#endif // #ifdef UnorderedMapBoost
```

I could then control at compile-time which one to use, and profiled it. In my case, the portability ended up being more important, so I normally use `std::map`.